# Error while trying to install and configure Hadoop on win 7

Tags: apache, windows-7, hadoop, cygwin

I am trying to install and configure apache hadoop for windows 7.

Everthing went fine untill i had to specify the path for java.

I am following this tutorial http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2012/01/installing-and-configuring-apache.html

I commented #export , with the one the author mention in the above mention article.
The error which i am getting is as follow

**/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 10: export: `C:\Java\jre7': not a valid identifier
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.**

as you can see, in the error message it is mention that JAVA_Home is not set, however i have set JAVA_Home.

One more update i am trying to configure Hadoop 1.1.2

Please help me with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set JAVA_HOME then it work fine..set java home using this link..

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

Answer (score 0):

You have to give unix path for location of java for example

```
c:/java/jre
```